# StarTeam - ignoring local file changes

Tags: starteam

If we initially check-in a configuration-type file as an item into a StarTeam project, is it possible to then have the file checked-out by clients where, any local changes to the file are subsequently ignored and not marked for check-in back into the repository?

Thanks in advance,
PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StarTeam folder properties contain a tab for file exclusions.  If a local file matches a pattern in that list and has not previously been added to the server, it will not appear in the GUI for check-in.

Unfortunately, if the client is checking the configuration file out from the view, the GUI for that view will track it.  If you were to able to store that file somewhere else and copy it to the local checkout as needed, then the file could be excluded at the folder level and not appear for edits in the GUI.

Another possible way to do this within a view is to add the configuration file, label it with a view label, then delete the file and add the filename to the folder's exclude list.  The file would be available for check-out at that label only.  This would keep the config file in the same view but prevent it from being edited.  Note that this makes it very difficult to update that file later, if needed.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the reply. This is the approach we had taken and it seems the most appropriate one for dealing with these types of configuration items.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to control it with security.  Though this would not prevent the file from being detected as changed, it would prevent it from actually being checked into the system.